# Date Regular Expression in Flex

Tags: regex, date, apache-flex

I have got a Regular Expression code for Validating 'Date' Format with MM/DD/YYYY. This is my regular expression code that I have tested in the website [RegExr](http://regexr.com/).

```
((0[13578]|1[02])31(18|19|20)[0-9]{2})|((01|0[3-9]|1[1-2])(29|30)(18|19|20)[0-9]{2})|((0[1-9]|1[0-2])(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])(18|19|20)[0-9]{2})|((02)29(((18|19|20)(04|08|[2468][048]|[13579][26]))|2000))
```

Well. Now I have applied this code in my Flex program. When compiling my Flex program I have got this error.

> warning, rule cannot be matched

So I have changed my regular Expression Just a bit easier. This is my new Regular expression code which is not valid for Leap Year.

> (0[1-9]|1[012])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])((19|20)\d\d)

When using this Regular Expression, I have not get any compiler error. But When I give the value '01202000' , I got parse Error. I don't know how to use this regular expression in my Flex Program ? What is Fault here ?

Comment: [I've failed to reproduce this behaviour.](http://regex101.com/r/gX6zE2/1)

Comment: How are you declaring the regex in your code?

Comment: date \'((0[13578]|1[02])31(18|19|20)[0-9]{2})|((01|0[3-9]|1[1-2])(29|30)(18|19|20)[0-9]{2})|((0[1-9]|1[0-2])(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])(18|19|20)[0-9]{2})|((02)29(((18|19|20)(04|08|[2468][048]|[13579][26]))|2000))\'
{date} { yylval.string = (char *) strdup(yytext);return DATE ; }